# How can I change the x-location of my seaborn violion plot to correspond to their float values?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I have made a violion plot, with distributions for different values of 'eta', namely 0, 0.1127, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.8873 and 1.0. When I now plot my data the seven distributions are all equally spaced from one another. I would like to change this such that the locations of the subplots correspond to the number denoted on the x-axis.

My code is as follows: all the y values are a 1D array filled with a bunch of numbers.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure


data0 = np.genfromtxt('Plots/Violin/lambda0.0.dat', skip_header=0)
y0 = data0[:,3]
x0 = np.full(len(y0),0)
data01 = np.genfromtxt('Plots/Violin/lambda0.1.dat', skip_header=0)
y01 = data01[:,3]
x01 = np.full(len(y01),0.1127)
data02 = np.genfromtxt('Plots/Violin/lambda0.25.dat', skip_header=0)
y02 = data02[:,3]
x02 = np.full(len(y02),0.25)
data03 = np.genfromtxt('Plots/Violin/lambda0.5.dat', skip_header=0)
y03 = data03[:,3]
x03 = np.full(len(y03),0.5)
data04 = np.genfromtxt('Plots/Violin/lambda0.75.dat', skip_header=0)
y04 = data04[:,3]
x04 = np.full(len(y04),0.75)
data05 = np.genfromtxt('Plots/Violin/lambda0.9.dat', skip_header=0)
y05 = data05[:,3]
x05 = np.full(len(y05),0.8873)
data06 = np.genfromtxt('Plots/Violin/lambda1.0.dat', skip_header=0)
y06 = data06[:,3]
x06 = np.full(len(y06),1.0)
y = np.concatenate((y0,y01,y02,y03,y04,y05,y06),axis=0)
x = np.concatenate((x0,x01,x02,x03,x04,x05,x06),axis=0)
figure(figsize=[20,10])
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
plt.ylim(top=20,bottom=10)
ax = sns.violinplot(x=x,y=y)
```

Apparently I don't have enough reputation to post an image (this is my first post). But here is a link to the current plot for clarity:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7JpN.jpg

Comment: maybe instead of reading from 7 different files that only you have, you should generate a dataset of random values so that everyone can run your code

Answer (score 0):

Your x axis is getting read as strings. Convert them to “float” type and you should be fine.

This should work:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure


data0 = np.genfromtxt('Plots/Violin/lambda0.0.dat', skip_header=0)
y0 = data0[:,3]
x0 = np.full(len(y0),float(0))
data01 = np.genfromtxt('Plots/Violin/lambda0.1.dat', skip_header=0)
y01 = data01[:,3]
x01 = np.full(len(y01),float(0.1127))
data02 = np.genfromtxt('Plots/Violin/lambda0.25.dat', skip_header=0)
y02 = data02[:,3]
x02 = np.full(len(y02),float(0.25))
data03 = np.genfromtxt('Plots/Violin/lambda0.5.dat', skip_header=0)
y03 = data03[:,3]
x03 = np.full(len(y03),float(0.5))
data04 = np.genfromtxt('Plots/Violin/lambda0.75.dat', skip_header=0)
y04 = data04[:,3]
x04 = np.full(len(y04),float(0.75))
data05 = np.genfromtxt('Plots/Violin/lambda0.9.dat', skip_header=0)
y05 = data05[:,3]
x05 = np.full(len(y05),float(0.8873))
data06 = np.genfromtxt('Plots/Violin/lambda1.0.dat', skip_header=0)
y06 = data06[:,3]
x06 = np.full(len(y06),float(1.0))
y = np.concatenate((y0,y01,y02,y03,y04,y05,y06),axis=0)
x = np.concatenate((x0,x01,x02,x03,x04,x05,x06),axis=0)
figure(figsize=[20,10])
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
plt.ylim(top=20,bottom=10)
ax = sns.violinplot(x=x,y=y)
```